# Is it bad idea to response on each request with same json structure?

Tags: rest

I'm going to design API in a way where each response from server has same json structure:

e.g. ,../api/user/{id}/service/{id}

So the top object in hierarchy is api, which can contain some info (verson) and low leveled data, if requested (in my case users array). At the same time each user has or omits services; I understand that it will provide some redundant data, but in my case it isn't critical;

So is that good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bad approach.
In this case you should return service resource

```
/api/user/{id}/service/{id}
```

In this case, user resource

```
/api/user/{id}
```

But you can add relations to this route, for example

```
/api/user/{id}?with=services
```